# Cannot convert NVARCHAR to datetime2 in stored procedure accessed by EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from C#

```
var dt = new SqlParameter("ExportedOn", DateTime.Now);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC LogDataExport @ExportedOn", dt);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LogDataExport
    (@ExportedOn DATETIME2)
AS 
    INSERT INTO dbo.DataExportLogging (Id, ExportedOn, Description, Text)
        SELECT 1, @ExportedOn, 'asd', 'dsasadfsdag'
GO
```

I get an error that `dt` cannot be converted from `NVARCHAR` to `Datetime2`.

Comment: Try specifying the datatype on the SqlParameter. `dt.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime2;`

Comment: Is it a compile time or runtime error? What is the **exact** error?

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` script for `DataExportLogging`.

Answer (score 0):

If you like server side solution you can set-up the `dbo.DataExportLogging.ExportedOn` column default value as `getdate()`.

Comment: That will get the date in the timezone of the database server rather than of the client app. So not _exactly_ the same.

Comment: If you're using `Datetime2` as your datatype (which **is** recommended!), you should also stop using `getdate()` and use `sysdatetime()` instead